# How to sort datasets for each stacked bar chart using React Chart.js 2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am currently unable to sort the datasets that shown in each stacked bars in descending order; they are currently displaying randomly.
Here is my current code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { claimStatues, demoClaimsValue, generateMockData } from './data.mock';
import { stackedBarChartOptions } from './Barchart.options';
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
);

const xLabels = [
  'In-patient',
  'Out-patient',
  'Dental',
  'Vision',
  'Vaccination',
  'Total permanent disability',
  'Critical illness',
  'Accident',
  'Maternity',
  'Death',
  'Others',
];

const dataPoints = [
  {
    label: 'Received',
    data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    backgroundColor: '#1F659F',
  },
  {
    label: 'Rejected',
    data: [20, 30, 10, 60, 70, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    backgroundColor: '#F44336',
  },
  {
    label: 'Processing',
    data: [30, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    backgroundColor: '#FFC107',
  },
  {
    label: 'Approved',
    data: [40, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
  },
  {
    label: 'Custom',
    data: [50, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
  },
];

export const data = {
  labels: xLabels,
  datasets: dataPoints.map((dataPoint) => ({
    ...dataPoint,
  })),
};

/**
 * 
 * generateMockData({
    columns: demoClaimsValue,
    statues: claimStatues,
  }),
 */
export default function BarChart() {
  return (
    <div className="relative bg-white">
      <Bar options={stackedBarChartOptions} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the package json

```
{
  "name": "rws-econcierge-cms",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "dev:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next build && next export",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod yarn build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.9",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.9",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.9",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.8",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.3.9",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.32.6",
    "antd": "^5.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "dnd-core": "^16.0.1",
    "dompurify": "^3.0.6",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.35.0",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "recoil": "^0.7.5",
    "recoil-persist": "^4.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6",
    "validator": "^13.11.0",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "18.7.18",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.9",
    "@types/validator": "^13.11.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "4.8.3"
  }
}
```

**I notice that the issues might be related to the data structure that i am using currently**

Below is the screen short to reference

[image]

- Want to sort datasets from high to low for each stacked bars

Comment: The bars are never displayed randomly; the image you attached shows that each stack has the bars in the same order, the order in which you defined `datasets` array: 'Received' at the bottom, then 'Approved', ..., and at the top 'Rejected' (obviously, some bars are not visible if the corresponding value is too small or zero). The same with the data in your code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfe657sr/). The colours follow each other in the same order in the stack. This is the how stacked bars are expected to behave; you can't change this order by a mapping of data.

Comment: If you want the bar sorted by their value (or any way other than the one in which they are added -- the order of colours and of the legend entries), you should consider using [floating](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html) bars instead of y-stacked bars; see [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/qfe657sr/1/) of the previous fiddle.

Comment: ok, are there alternative libraries or tools, such as D3.js, that I can use to achieve the same functionality [KiKon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16466946/kikon)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve. I thought you wanted the bars sorted by value, which is what the solution I gave in the message above does. Can you please explain in which order do you want the bars to appear; maybe an image could help

Comment: I tested the code in the provided fiddle on my local server, but it's not working as expected. I might have missed something in my implementation.
Here is the [result](https://imgur.com/kTY474G)

Comment: @kikon, here is the sanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-glitter-h3qr33?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C50) for code reference

Comment: To apply that piece of code you have to remove the `stacked` property of y scale  (or set it false) `options.scales.y.stacked: false`

Comment: @kikon, after setting options.scales.y.stacked: false, the bars are no longer floating in the chart. However, they're still not in the correct order. For instance, in the In-Patient column, 'custom' should be at the top, followed by the lower values.
code [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-glitter-h3qr33?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A65%2C29)

Comment: They appear to be sorted with the smallest value on top and largest at the bottom. If you want the other way around just reverse the sign in the `sort` function

Comment: Finally, its now working correctly [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-glitter-h3qr33?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A72%2C20), Thanks @kikon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars are never displayed randomly; the image you attached shows that each stack has the bars in the same order, the order in which you defined datasets array: 'Received' at the bottom, then 'Approved', ..., and at the top 'Rejected' (obviously, some bars are not visible if the corresponding value is too small or zero).

The colours follow each other in the same order in the stack; this is also the order of the items in the legend. This is the how stacked bars are expected to behave; users also expect that and can easily read such a chart. You can't change this order by a mapping of data.

If you want to change the order of the bars as to sort them by their values, you could use [floating bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html); you have to disable `scales.y.stacked` option (default is `false`) and specify for each item both two numbers in an array: its base and its top.

Here's an example of that approach with a `sort` of the data in your post.

```js
const xLabels = [
     'In-patient',
     'Out-patient',
     'Dental',
     'Vision',
     'Vaccination',
     'Total permanent disability',
     'Critical illness',
     'Accident',
     'Maternity',
     'Death',
     'Others',
];

const dataPoints = [
     {
          label: 'Received',
          data: [20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
          backgroundColor: '#1F659F',
     },
     {
          label: 'Rejected',
          data: [20, 30, 10, 60, 70, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
          backgroundColor: '#F44336',
     },
     {
          label: 'Processing',
          data: [30, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
          backgroundColor: '#FFC107',
     },
     {
          label: 'Approved',
          data: [40, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 120],
          backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
     },
     {
          label: 'Custom',
          data: [50, 10, 20, 80, 90, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
          backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
     },
];


const datasets = dataPoints.map((dataPoint) => ({
     ...dataPoint,
})); // if they need to be copied

datasets[0].data.forEach((_, datasetIndex)=>{ // all .data arrays should have equal length for this to work
     const all_i = datasets.map((d, dataIndex)=>[d.data[datasetIndex], dataIndex])
          .sort(([data1], [data2]) => data1 - data2);
     let sum = 0;
     all_i.forEach(
          ([data, datasetIdx]) => {
               datasets[datasetIdx].data[datasetIndex] = [sum, sum + data];
               sum = sum + data;
          }
     );
});

const data = {
     labels: xLabels,
     datasets,
};

const config = {
     type: 'bar',
     data: data,
     options: {
          responsive: true,
          scales:{
               x: {
                    stacked: true,
               },
               // y:{
               //    stacked: true
               // }
          },
     },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


 <div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
 </div>
```